# C# Maps - RouteQuery giving a false route

Tags: c#, geolocation, gps, bing-maps, routes

So I have a Bing Map control, a GeoCordWatcher getting gps lat and lon, a timer for position intervals and a RouteQuery maker turning the GPS cords into a path for the map.

The points are correct, +- a couple of meters. The problem is that if I am near an intersection or a side street it when the route query runs it takes me off on a half mile expedition that I never went on.

I have tried using both default accuracy and high accuracy but I get the same results. Actually seems to be worse with high accuracy.

Has anyone else had this issue?

```
            RouteQuery rq = new RouteQuery();
            List<GeoCoordinate> cords = new List<GeoCoordinate>();
            foreach (classes.PositionObj posObj in waypoints)
            {
                cords.Add(new GeoCoordinate(Convert.ToDouble(posObj.Lattitude), Convert.ToDouble(posObj.Longitude)));
            }
            rq.Waypoints = cords;
            rq.QueryCompleted += rw_QueryCompleted;
            rq.QueryAsync();


    void rw_QueryCompleted(object sender, QueryCompletedEventArgs<Route> e)
    {
        try { 
            if (e.Error == null)
            {
                Route myroute = e.Result;                
                mapRoute = new MapRoute(myroute);
                mapRoute.Color = (Color)Application.Current.Resources["PhoneAccentColor"];
                myMap.AddRoute(mapRoute);          
            }
        }
        catch (Exception error) { MessageBox.Show(error.Message); MessageBox.Show(error.StackTrace); leaveFeedback(error.StackTrace); }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't been able to test it yet but I think that this is the answer I am looking for.

```
 rq.RouteOptimization = RouteOptimization.MinimizeDistance;
```

This is the documentation I found

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.maps.services.routeoptimization(v=vs.105).aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.maps.services.routequery(v=vs.105).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Try the code:

```
routeQuery.TravelMode = TravelMode.Driving;
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others. This post was flagged for deletion by some other user, presumably because it lacked such an explanation.